# python 3.x range function calculation sum Einrückung

Tags: python, math

Python Code:

```
b=0
for x in range (4): 
    a=b+x 
print (a)
```

Why is the outcome 3 and not the 6, i.e. 0+1+2+3?

Comment: Because `b` shall forever be `0`. Integers are immutable. Also, it's not clear where the `print` actually occurs because of your incorrect indentation

Comment: Why not use the built-in `sum`:- `print(sum(range(4)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are setting a to what b is, which is 0 plus x, every time you call this you are overwriting the value of a, I have rewritten your code and hope it helps.

```
b=0 #Sets the value of b to 0
for x in range(4): #this will run the code below 4 times
    b=b+x #makes b equal to itself, plus the vaue of x.

print(b) #outputs the value of b
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you are always **updating** a not summing its values and there is no need of `b=0`:

```
a = 0
for x in range (4): 
    a+=x 
print (a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reassigning every time the value of `a`.

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
b=0
x=0 
a=b+x # a = 0 +0
x=1
a=b+x # a = 0 + 1
x=2
a=b+x #a = 0 + 2
x=3
a=b+x #a = 0 + 3
print (a) # 3 is the final value of a
```

What I think you wanted to do is:

```
a=0
for x in range(4):
    a += x # or equivalently a = a+x
print(a)
```

I do not understand why you used also variable `b`.

Note also a more compact solution:

```
a = sum(range(4))
```